# mysql subpartitions, partition for every minute

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I should do subpartitions for example 1440 *(1min) for everyday.
also 15min*96 for everyday...

I don´t know how to do it.

Best Regards

```
CREATE TABLE `event9` (         

`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,       

 `date_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,       

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`date_time`)        

) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1         

PARTITION BY RANGE ( day(date_time))         

SUBPARTITION .. ..
```

Comment: First you should read the `preface` here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/partition-maintenance/ and then probably throw away the idea to use partitions.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is here... SUBPARTTION BY HASH (minute(date_time)) the minute resets every hour. I would like to have counting from 1 to 1440) without any resets. If I do it with hour it works

Comment: Why are you partitioning?  If you want performance, do not use `SUBPARTITIONs`.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. Purpose of partitioning is better performance in delete data: drop partition